# A tricky Data Merge or Mail merge

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I am looking for a solution where I can convert the spreadsheet data about [who] has [how many of] [what item] to PDF pages that contains a grid of item name with item picture. It's easiest for me to explain by the attached sketch. Please look at the sketch.

I feel the most difficult part is this:
If you would you have 3 of item B, then it needs to repeat to say item B three times.

I know how to convert spreadsheet into PDF with using mail(or data) merge using InDesign.

thank you so much for helping !!

[data merge result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV1Fs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little radical, but if you can rearrange your data into a table then you may be do something like this screenshot:

[image]

In column A you have the owner/custodian, and in column B you have the picture of the item. In my example bob owns two waterfalls, so the waterfall picture shows twice. The key is to go to the picture properties and click on the item `Move and size with cells` (credit goes to [answer by vr286](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776611/insert-picture-into-excel-cell)).

Now you can filter by owner and print to pdf from directly from excel. If you need, notice how I added a keyword in the item, you can create a matrix in another tab and use `countifs()` to create your summary matrix you show as a picture.